# Open set in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Show if U is a nonempty open set of a topological space X and U is a subset of S, then the closure of X\S is a subset of X\U?

I know that U is open so X\U is closed and X\S is a subset of X\U since U is a subset of S. How do.I know if S is closed or open?

Comment: You don’t need to know if S is closed or open or anything. The result is true for any such S.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $U$ is open, hence $X \backslash U$ is closed. If we let $U$ be a subset of $S$, then $X \backslash S \subset X \backslash U$, clearly.

The closure of $X \backslash S$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $X \backslash S$. $X \backslash U$ is one such set, and it is closed as we mentioned earlier. It follows that $\overline{X \backslash S} \subset X \backslash U$, since it is the intersection of some sets out of which $X \backslash U$ is one.

Note : the above follows whether or not $S$ is open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

X\U is a closed set that contains the closure of X\S.

Every closed set that contains a set B also contains the closure, $\bar{B}$ since, by definition, $\bar{B}$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain B.

$$\bar{B} = \cap C_x$$

Where $C_x$ is any closed set that contains B.  In other words, it is the “smallest closed set that contains B”.

Taking $B$ to be X\S, we have from the first line that X\U is one such closed $C_x$. So you immediately have your result that $\bar{B} \subset$  X\U.